# Contar a quantidade de caracteres de uma String?

Tags: java

preciso contar a quantidade de caracteres total de uma String quando a palavra for digitada. Gostaria de saber como criar o código, acredito que seja um for.

```
public class ExercicioDeString {
    public String transformarParaMaiusculo(String texto) {
    return texto.toUpperCase();
}

public String transformarParaMinusculo(String texto) {
    return texto.toLowerCase();
}

public String contarLetras(String texto) {

}

}
```

Tentei usar o .lenght(); mas não consegui.

[image: Erro]
[image: Erri2]

Comment: Precisar ser contato enquanto a pessoa vai digitando? Por que para contar é só usar o texto.lenght();

Comment: Estou tentando fazer isso mas acusa um erro, vou atualizar o código e mostrar as imagens, para melhor entendimento.

Comment: E não precisa ser enquanto a pessoa vai digitando, somente depois da palava já digitada.

Comment: Reverti seu post, pois a cada edit você está mudando o problema. Conforme já respondi, era um erro de tipo e um erro no return. Quando você edita uma pergunta mudando o sentido, invalida as respostas dadas, quando for assim poste em separdo o novo problema

Comment: a blz, desculpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso seja só o tamanho da string:

```
 suaVariavel.length();
```

O erro no seu código é primeiro que você não está retornando nem exibindo o valor, segundo, o tipo de dado deve ser inteiro, não string, assim sua função fica algo como:

```
public int ContaCaracteres(String texto){
   return texto.length();
}
```

Comment: Estou tentando fazer isso mas acusa um erro, vou atualizar o código e mostrar as imagens, para melhor entendimento.

Comment: O duro é que depois do seu [edit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/370771/revisions) ficou basicamente a mesma coisa que eu já tinha respondido. De qq forma ficou mais completinha agora (só o length que está digitado errado).

Comment: Realmente falta de atenção minha, mas no .lenght continua acusando algo... veja a nova imagem.

Comment: Se eu uso int ou Int dá outro erro, estou usando Integer, está funcionando, estou fazendo o teste por uma classe de test pelo Junity também...

Answer (score 9):

Erro básico de tipo.

Se quer retonar um número na função, é `public int` ou `public Integer` e não `public String`

```
public Integer contarLetras(String texto) {
    return texto.length();
}
```

Além disso faltou o `return` no seu codigo.

Já foge da pergunta, mas note que você tem o primitivo `int` e a classe `Integer` em Java, dependendo da intenção precisa ver qual é melhor para cada caso.

O primitivo só aceita números, a classe é nulável.

Comment: Realmente falta de atenção minha, mas no .lenght continua acusando algo... veja a nova imagem.

Comment: Só para entender que você só não vai usar o return quando o método for do tipo static void.

Comment: @JulioVieira vc digitou errado, é length e não lenght

Comment: Nossa, que descuido, era isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Pena que vc marcou certa a resposta que foi consertada só depois da minha, mas o importante é que resolveu (só dá pra marcar uma)

Comment: @JulioVieira a resposta do Bacco esta bem completa, fora que fala de uma diferença básica do Integer e do int, claro que dava para estender o assunto, mas fugiria do foco. Parabéns Bacco, fico feliz de ver que ainda tem alguns poucos bons usuários com intuito de trazer a resposta e ainda agregar explicações técnicas para quem quer se tornar programador de verdade e entender como funciona de fato com o que trabalha.

Comment: @Jaffe.Marques tem histórico com data e hora, suas 2 edições vieram depois da minha, inclusive a que conserta o length errado (só depois que eu comentei). Concordo que seja bom vc corrigir, mas a sua original nao passava nem perto de resolver o problema, só por isso mencionei. - não acho ruim vc ter consertado, só acho importante o autor da pergunta entender como funciona o sistema para ser justo e deixar o site melhor organizado.

Comment: Galera desculpem ai o transtorno que causei, sou iniciante por aqui, mas agradeço a todos que me ajudaram!

Comment: @Jaffe.Marques novamente, nada contra sua postagem. Só estou explicando pro autor entender a sequencia das coisas. Seu post está correto e agora mais completo entao ta tudo bem. Nao é pelos pontos, é apenas para que o autor avalie bem em futras ocasiões

Comment: @Jaffe.Marques não acharia justo vc remover a sua. Pra mim agora que a sua está correta nao vejo problemas na aceitação. Jajá vou dar uma limpa nos comments aqui para na deixar bagunça nos posts que foge da pergunta.

Comment: Eu errei em modificar a pergunta com as imagens, devia ter colocado já as imagens de inicio, mas ficarei atento quando for fazer uma nova pergunta!

Comment: @JulioVieira ao invés de imagens de preferencia sempre coloque texto, fotos de códigos é algo muito complicado de testar ;)